# jQuery Autocomplete no drop down suggestion

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, autocomplete

I have a form in my page and I wanted to add autocomplete to suggest some already existing names to the user

When I type in the 'name' input text box, I see in my console that it retrieves existing name starting with whatever letter I type... but I do not see any sort of drop down to select the suggestion on the web page. Am I missing something? How do I get the dropdown of suggested autocomplete?

```
<script src="{% static '/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#id_name").on('keyup', function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'ajax-autocomplete' %}",
        data: {
          'search': value
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            list = data.list;
            $("#id_name").autocomplete({
            source: list,
            minLength: 3
            });
        }
    });
  });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `datalist` and populate it dinamically:

```
<input list="listName" id="inputName" type="text" autocomplete="off">
<datalist id="listName"></datalist>
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/my_api_url',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (jsonData) {
        $('#listName').empty();
        jsonData.forEach(function (person) {
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = person.name;
            $('#listName').append(option);
        });            
    }
});
```